# WSO2 ESB Proxy-Service Import XSD error

Tags: xsd, wsdl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to connect ServiceManager WSDL to WSO2 esb as a target for a proxy service. I installed both SM9 and WSO2esb on the same dev system. SoapSonar will be used to check the results of my esb configuration.

My service definition looks the following way:

```
    <proxy name="SM9Lcl1IM" transports="http" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable" statistics="enable">
    <description>Incident Management Local SM9</description>
    <target>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://localhost:19380/sc62server/PWS"/>
        </endpoint>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:19380/sc62server/PWS/IncidentManagement.wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```

Unfortunatly I can't solve the problem, that xsd files have to be transferred to the client. SoapSonar tells me by a popup window, that it wants to know, where it can find

```
SM9Lcl1IM?xsd=http://VMDEMOW2K3:19380/sc62server/PWS/Common.xsd
```

I checked the wsdl and found the following statement:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" schemaLocation="http://VMDEMOW2K3:19380/sc62server/PWS/Common.xsd"/>'
```

So I tried several things:

- I copied the WSDL inline, defined a location/key-pair and tried to define the key in the user registry
- I checked the synapse documentation ... it seems that they also had issues with this in older days. Neither of the suggestions could be configured in WS=2. I tried it in Synapse as well - same issue. I tried the proxy example of synapse (synapse.xml in the misc/proxy folder) - this works! Ah ... so it should work somehow ...
- I figured arround lots of time with the GUi of WSO2 as well as with the xml-configuration of a separate synapse installation. Nothing worked.

Is there a hint or a setup guide, that solves this issue? THe samples are nice, but they are a bit too simple to derive a solution out of them.

Comment: I solved this problem little differently. Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792427/wso2-esb-customuri-serviceuri-with-expression/17821797#17821797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved, but the solution doesn't satisfy me. I included the contents of the xsd into the wsdl, so there is no import necessairy. The solution works, but turns the modular concept of xsd upside down.

I think, the problem is related to an older bug in synapse (underlying in wso2 esb), and as far as it seems, it is not finaly solved at all.

If you have a better solution, please let me know, since I'd like to have one, that supports the modular concept.

Comment: This is exactly the issue. Link to bug report: [https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2697](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2697)

Comment: Another approach that might work for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338785/creating-wso2-esb-proxy-service-on-an-endpoint-which-has-references-to-xsd/17405926#17405926](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338785/creating-wso2-esb-proxy-service-on-an-endpoint-which-has-references-to-xsd/17405926#17405926)